# calling perl script that takes multiple input args in python

Tags: python

Need help with integrating perl script with main python script.

I have a perl script by name: `GetHostByVmname.pl`

```
./GetHostByVmname.pl –server 10.0.1.191 –username Administrator –password P@ssword1 –vmname RHTest
```

I need to call above script from my python main script. Tried below, but doesn’t work:

```
param = "--server 10.0.1.191 --username Administrator --password P@ssword1 --vmname RHTest"


pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./GetHostByVmname.pl", param ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: the above code threw an error like this: Unknown option: server 10.0.1.191 --username Administrator --password P@ssword1 --vmname RHTest
For a summary of command usage, type './GetHostByVmname.pl --help'.
For documentation, type 'perldoc ./GetHostByVmname.pl'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be better when you split string

```
./GetHostByVmname.pl –server 10.0.1.191 –username Administrator –password P@ssword1 –vmname RHTest
```

to a list, and after call Popen with this list as a first param.
Example:

```
import shlex, subprocess
args_str = "./GetHostByVmname.pl –server 10.0.1.191 –username Administrator –password P@ssword1 –vmname RHTest"
args = shlex.split(args_str)
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either provide a shell command

```
Popen("./GetHostByVmname.pl –server 10.0.1.191 ...", ...)
```

Or an array where the the first element is the program and the rest are args.

```
Popen(["./GetHostByVmname.pl", "–server", "10.0.1.191", ... ], ...)
```

Currently, you are doing the equivalent of the following shell command:

```
perl ./GetHostByVmname.pl '–server 10.0.1.191 ...'
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tested the solution from Alexey. But essentially both your solutions are the same.